# Confused about low-quality answers

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

I've been recently declined a "Very Low Quality" flag on this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874819/remove-a-0-after-the-decimal-point) and so I started wondering if I was doing something wrong.

I searched on meta and found several discussions, including this: [Why were these "Very low quality" flags declined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189362/why-were-these-very-low-quality-flags-declined/189373#189373)

Quoting the accepted answer:

> When you're flagging a post as Very Low Quality, it's as if you're saying the following:
>
> This content should not exist. Delete it. Now. It is not salvageable through editing.

Now, coming back to the first answer, how is that has been closed as "Off topic" but my "Very Low Quality" flag has been declined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Now, coming back to the first answer, how is that has been closed as "Off topic" but my "Very Low Quality" flag has been declined?

Because those aren't the same thing. A "Very Low Quality" flag is asking for the post to simply be deleted. An off-topic close vote is giving the author of the post a chance to fix it, in this case by including their code in the post.

Comment: It is still a one-liner answer (see comments), so how is this not a "Very Low Quality" question?

Comment: @domokun Why do you think that makes it a VLQ question?

Comment: Because I believe that users should be discouraged to ask questions that have trivial answers. There is already Google for that.
That question, for example, shows absolutely no signs of research or even attempts at tackling the solution. Am I wrong in thinking this kind of questions only pollute SO?

Comment: @domokun That's a reason to downvote the question, not flag it.